# wordpress site with asp subdomain?

Tags: php, asp.net

So I have been assigned a project to develop a website, for a company. Their old website is built in asp.net and it makes references to ms sql server (2005). I chose Wrodpress (having no prior experience with web development) now, I finished the static part in wordpress but I would also have to redo their MyAccount (a client portal) which stores info in the sql server and retrieves it when someone logs on. I don't know PHP that well to mimic and yield similar results. So would it be possible (and excuse me if this is a silly question) to put the Wordpress site on II7 and keep the asp.net pages as a subdomain? Until I convert the entire thing over to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [host Wordpress in IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/280/install-wordpress-on-iis/).

Yes, you can have a separate web site on a separate sub domain built on ASP.NET. You may need to have separate IP addresses or even separate web servers, but you can do it. Talk to your network administrator.

Do you want to in the long run? No.

The best thing to do here is to learn PHP or ASP.NET and implement the entire website in one of those frameworks. You can use pretty much any database you want with any framework you want. However, certain frameworks will have more features for certain databases (ASP.NET favors MS SQL Server and PHP favors MySQL). But there are MS SQL Server libraries for both PHP and ASP.NET.

I can't speak for PHP (my knowledge is limited and outdated), but a great place for ASP.NET is http://www.asp.net/.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am learning PHP and eventually will convert the entire site to PHP, however the client portal seems like a difficult project from where I'm standing, not to even mention that Crystal Reports come into picture :( Again, thank you!!!